# Sed command replicating substitution twice

Tags: linux, sed, terminal

I have a simple file with this content stored on temp.txt

```
Here I lay in the depths of hell waiting to be rescued by my charming warrior.
```

Once I use the sed command to substitute

```
sed -i "s/hell/HELL/p" ./temp.txt
```

This is the result I get

```
Here I lay in the depths of HELL waiting to be rescued by my charming warrior.
Here I lay in the depths of HELL waiting to be rescued by my charming warrior.
```

any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The /p flag duplicates the line. So avoid it if you just want to replace the occurrence. So the command will be:

```
sed -i "s/hell/HELL/" ./temp.txt
```

And your file will be:

```
Here I lay in the depths of HELL waiting to be rescued by my charming warrior.
```